# What kind of ruby method call is Array(x)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

What is the meaning, and where is the Ruby documentation for the syntax of:

```
Array(phrases)
```

which I found browsing the Rails source here:

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb, line 109
...
119:           match = Array(phrases).map { |p| Regexp.escape(p) }.join('|')
```

I thought that Array.new would normally be used to create an array, so something different must be going on here.  BTW from the context around this code, the `phrases` variable can be either a string or an array of strings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's most likely the `Kernel#Array` method, see [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005989).  It's slightly different than `Array.new`; it's more of a cast into an array.  (It tries `to_ary` and `to_a`.)

Answer (score 2):

Array(x) appears to act exactly the same as  x.to_a.

@Brian is right - it's a method of Kernel.  Pickaxe says:

**Array( arg ) -> anArray**

Returns arg .to_a.

```
Array(1..5)  » [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the [`Kernel#Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#M005989) method, as others have already stated.

But the Ruby documentation does not give credit to this method's usefulness in simplifying your code. Also it does not tell you that objects which don't have a `to_ary` or a `to_a` method are encapsulated in an array.

```
Array([1,2,3])        -> [1,2,3]
Array(1..3)           -> [1,2,3]
Array({ a: 1, b: 2 }) -> [[:a, 1],[:b,2]]
Array("Hello World")  -> ["Hello World"]
Array(1)              -> [1]
```

All these features of `Kernel#Array` allow you to handle typical corner cases with parameters in one single line.

See this code, which is a typical situation in many APIs or DSLs:

```
# data can be nil, a single value or an array
def handle(data)
  data ||= Array.new   #Case 1: Data is nil
  data = [data] unless data.is_a?(Array)   #Case 2: Data is a single value
  data.each { |d| ... }
end
```

This can be simplified by using `Kernel#Array`:

```
def handle(data)
  Array(data).each { |d| ... }
end
```

Of course one has to be careful with providing different types for the `data` parameter, because the `to_ary`/`to_a` methods might or might not give you what you expect.