# How are shortcuts like Array(arg) and String(arg) defined?

Tags: ruby

If `Array` and `String` are class definitions, how are these things defined?

```
def whatever(some_input)
  some_input = Array(some_input)
end
```

How does that get invoked?  Can we add this behaviour to our own classes, or is this only for core classes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kind of ruby method call is Array(x)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358039/what-kind-of-ruby-method-call-is-arrayx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're actually methods on [Kernel](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html):

```
>> Kernel.methods.select { |m| m =~ /^[A-Z]/ }
=> [:Array, :Complex, :Float, :Integer, :Rational, :String, :URI]
```

And [Object includes Kernel](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#includes-section) so these methods are available everywhere. You can make methods whose names begin with an upper case letter, it just isn't that common.

[Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) does similar things with the `Nokogiri::HTML` and `Nokogiri::XML` constructors. For example, in Nokogiri you will find this:

```
module Nokogiri
  class << self
    ###   
    # Parse HTML.  Convenience method for Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse
    def HTML thing, url = nil, encoding = nil, options = XML::ParseOptions::DEFAULT_HTML, &block
      Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(thing, url, encoding, options, &block)
    end
  end  
  #...
end
```

so `HTML` is just a standard method with non-standard name.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I remember Nokogiri using the same syntax. Makes perfect sense, thanks!

Comment: similar Hash[...] constructor is found here: http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D

Comment: @tokland: Similar idea but you can `def self.[](...)` to get that, you can't overload `()` (the "function call operator") in Ruby though so you need things like the Kernel hack.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can show that `Array(arg)` is defined as a method is by using `defined?`

```
defined?(Integer()) # => "method"
```