# How to treat a ruby class as a method?

Tags: ruby

I've seen Ruby code with classes called like methods:

```
FactoryGirl(:factory_name) # => returns a factory instance
```

How do you write that 'method'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kind of ruby method call is Array(x)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358039/what-kind-of-ruby-method-call-is-arrayx)

Comment: See also [How are shortcuts like `Array(arg)` and `String(arg)` defined?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/7695151/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is to create a function with the same name as the class and that forwards its parameters to the class' `new` method.  For instance:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(x)
    @arg=x
  end

  def to_s
    @arg.to_s
  end
end

def Foo(x)
  Foo.new(x)
end

a = Foo.new(7)
a.class
=> Foo
puts a
=> 7
b = Foo(7)
b.class
=> Foo
puts b
=> 7
```

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, it's [defined in `lib/factory_girl/syntax/vintage.rb`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/lib/factory_girl/syntax/vintage.rb) at the bottom:

```
module FactoryGirl
  module Syntax
    module Vintage
      # [other stuff elided]

      # Shortcut for Factory.create.
      #
      # Example:
      #   Factory(:user, name: 'Joe')
      def Factory(name, attrs = {})
        ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn 'Factory(:name) is deprecated; use FactoryGirl.create(:name) instead.', caller
        FactoryGirl.create(name, attrs)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add this factory-function to the Object-class:

```
  class Object
    def FactoryGirl(symbol)
      ...
    end
  end
```